# jQuery Autocomplete Combobox - Clear selection on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

With the jQueryUI Comboxbox widget, how can I self-reference the `input` element? In the code below, I would like the `.click()` event to clear the value of the `input` and the `.blur()` event to reassign the previous value.

```
this.input = $('<input id="somebox">')
  .click(function() { ??? })
  .blur(function() { ??? })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I understand what you really want to do.
But the below code will do literally what you said.

```
this.input = $('<input id="somebox">')
  .click(function() { this.preValue = $(this).val(); $(this).val('');})
  .blur(function() { $(this).val(this.preValue);})
```